# UWP RichEditBox RightClick->Paste is not triggering Paste event

Tags: c#, uwp

When I press Ctrl + V inside the RichEditBox control, it's triggering the Paste event handler. But it doesn't trigger Paste event handler when do Right Click -> Paste. Instead it's pasting the copied image in the RichEditBox.

[image]
[image]

```
<RichEditBox Name="EditorBox" Paste="EditorBox_Paste" />
```

I have to perform some operation in Paste event handler before the image is pasted.

How do I trigger Paste event handler, in Right Click -> Paste.

Comment: When I used the code and right-click->paste, it can trigger the Paste event in RichEditBox. What is your vs version and system version? And have you done other behaviors?

Comment: VS Version is 15.9.15, System is WIndows 10 pro. Other behaviors?

Answer (score 1):

By testing, if you set version 1903(build 18362) to the Target version, the Paste event can be triggered, but other versions can't. So you can try to use the latest version to see if the same issue occur.

Or you can also customize a menuflyout to replace the TextCommandBarFlyout which is used in RichEditBox and define it's click event. You need to notice the TextCommandBarFlyout only can be used above 1809.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <MenuFlyout x:Key="MYFLYOUT">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Paste" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click"></MenuFlyoutItem>
    </MenuFlyout>

</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <RichEditBox Name="EditorBox" ContextFlyout="{StaticResource MYFLYOUT}" Paste="EditorBox_Paste" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Is there any way to modify the default available context menu flyout, so that I can trigger paste event separately? Because I would require other options like Copy, Undo, Redo, etc of the default context menu flyout.

Comment: The default context menu flyout cannot be modified directly, it can only be replaced. So if you want to use the default flyout, you need to change your version to 18362, because in that verison, the Paste event can be triggered. Otherwise, you should customize a menuflyout to replace the default flyout.